# Test Facebook Ads API - sandbox?

Tags: facebook-ads-api

We would like to develop an app based on Facebook Ads API but I'm wondering how we can test it? Does Facebook have some kind of sandbox for ads api as well?

Comment: They don't provide sandbox mode for Ads API. You can test by creating real campaigns on real account but you don't have to start them, so you will not spend a lot of money.

Comment: @aine has the answer, we launched sandbox ad account for developers. Each facebook App can get at least one sandbox ad account for development.

Answer (score 11):

Facebook just released a sandbox mode for the Marketing API. Here is the blog post: https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2016/10/19/sandbox-ad-accounts